# MongoDB, slow chunk Migration for collection `config.system.sessions` with removeShard

Tags: mongodb, performance, load-balancing, sharding, latency

##### Details of the environment/setup:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- MongoDB 6.0
- Sharded Cluster with 3 shards + 1 config server. (Note: each component has replication enabled, but no replicas as this is just a test by hand)
- Cluster Components are hosted by LXD containers
- Little to no data is written to the cluster, only testing things out.

##### Problem:

When I remove the shard that hosts the `config.system.sessions` collection, drainage takes about 20-25 minutes.

When I look at the logs for this shard I see `"Slow query"`:

```
2023-10-25T11:49:21Z charmed-mongodb.mongod[4753]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-10-25T11:49:21.835+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn179","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"_shardsvrMoveRange":"config.system.sessions","toShard":"shard-one","min":{"_id":{"id":{"$uuid":"83400000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}}},"waitForDelete":false,"epoch":{"$oid":"6538e3c125ae3b07d28d5eaf"},"fromShard":"shard-three","maxChunkSizeBytes":200000,"forceJumbo":2,"secondaryThrottle":false,"writeConcern":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1698234561,"i":1}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"BDUe5gGly3g4iPDSiuCwtTRJTLU=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":7293828730399490051}},"$configTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1698234561,"i":1}},"$topologyTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1698233824,"i":2}},"mayBypassWriteBlocking":false,"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":236,"locks":{},"writeConcern":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0,"provenance":"clientSupplied"},"remote":"10.18.246.22:60792","protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":536}}
```

##### My Questions

1. **Why is this query slow?**
2. **How can I make this query faster?**
3. **Is this related to the shard key for this collection? AFAICT `mongod`/`mongos` sets this collection up. Is it okay to change the shard key?**

##### Additional Information

From the docs: [config.system.sessions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/config-database/#collections-to-support-sessions)

There is 1024 chunks in this collection, and here is more useful info from `sh.status()` before removing:

```
    database: { _id: 'config', primary: 'config', partitioned: true },
    collections: {
      'config.system.sessions': {
        shardKey: { _id: 1 },
        unique: false,
        balancing: true,
        chunkMetadata: [ { shard: 'shard-two', nChunks: 1024 } ],
        chunks: [
          'too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print'
        ],
        tags: []
      }
```

I have also logged into the machines hosting the shards/config servers and seen that on each:

- that CPU consumption was low (tested with `top`)
- connectivity with other components was fast (used `iperf` for this)
- checked disk space and there was plenty

I have also logged into the shard hosting the collection and ran:

```
use config
db.system.sessions.stats()
```

and saw:

```
  sharded: false,
```

this seems wrong, but I am not sure.

I thought I would try re-sharding the collection, but when I tried to view the collection contents with `config> db.system.sessions.find()` I got:

```
MongoServerError: not authorized on config to execute command { find: "system.sessions", filter: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("2b7221a9-41ce-457b-a1e0-a1caf417b012") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1698306641, 2), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 7DAE0335273F250F7F1469FD3167EBAA61253250), keyId: 7293828730399490051 } }, $db: "config" }
```